# Numpy mean of nonzero values

Tags: python, numpy, mean, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix of size N*M and I want to find the mean value for each row. The values are from 1 to 5 and entries that do not have any value are set to 0. However, when I want to find the mean using the following method, it gives me the wrong mean as it also counts the entries that have value of 0.

```
matrix_row_mean= matrix.mean(axis=1)
```

How can I get the mean of only nonzero values?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Get the count of non-zeros in each row and use that for averaging the summation along each row. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
np.true_divide(matrix.sum(1),(matrix!=0).sum(1))
```

If you are on an older version of NumPy, you can use float conversion of the count to replace `np.true_divide`, like so -

```
matrix.sum(1)/(matrix!=0).sum(1).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [160]: matrix
Out[160]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [161]: np.true_divide(matrix.sum(1),(matrix!=0).sum(1))
Out[161]: array([ 1.5,  1.5,  1. ,  2. ])
```

---

Another way to solve the problem would be to replace zeros with `NaNs` and then use `np.nanmean`, which would ignore those `NaNs` and in effect those original `zeros`, like so -

```
np.nanmean(np.where(matrix!=0,matrix,np.nan),1)
```

From performance point of view, I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: np has no attribute true_divide

Comment: The masked array approach is compact (but not necessarily faster): `np.ma.masked_equal(matrix, 0).mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 20):

I will detail here the more general solution that uses a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/maskedarray.html). To illustrate the details let's create an lower triangular matrix with only ones:

```
matrix = np.tril(np.ones((5, 5)), 0)
```

If you the terminology above is not clear this matrix looks like this:

```
  [[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]
```

Now, we want our function to return an average of 1 for each of rows. Or in other words that the mean over the axis 1 is equal to a vector of five ones. In order to achieve this we created a masked matrix **where the entries whose values are zero are considered invalid**. This can be achieved with`np.ma.masked_equal`:

```
masked = np.ma.masked_equal(matrix, 0)
```

Finally we perform numpy operations in this array that will systematically ignore the masked elements (the 0's). With this in mind we obtain the desired result by:

```
masked.mean(axis=1)
```

This should produce a vector whose entries are only ones.

---

In more detail the output of `np.ma.masked_equal(matrix, 0)` should look like this:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 -- -- -- --]
 [1.0 1.0 -- -- --]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 -- --]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 --]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]],
             mask =
 [[False  True  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False]],
       fill_value = 0.0)
```

This indicates that eh values on `--` are considered invalid. This is also shown in the mask attribute of the masked arrays as True **which indicates that IT IS an invalid element** and therefore should be ignored.

Finally the output of the mean operation on this array should is:

```
masked_array(data = [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0],
             mask = [False False False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: really clear explanation with great simple examples. .. thanks !