# compute user mean ratings for only his specified ratings - Pearson similarity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, mean

I want to calculate the mean ratings for each user using **his specified ratings**.

I built a ratings matrix from my ratings dataframe as follow:

```
ratings_pivot = filter_ratings.pivot('User_id','item_id','Rating').fillna(0).astype(int).values
```

But then didn't know how to consider only nonzero values when calculating. The method mean() provided by numpy, if used on axis = 1 it will consider all elements values even those equal to zero.

How to do it?

Comment: Something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542548/?

Comment: Where's your data?

Comment: @Divakar yes! thanks didn't find it before writing the question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I didn't put it because it's not needed for the question. I wanted to find a way to consider only nonzero values when calculating mean over each row of the matrix.

Comment: In that case, I think your question can be closed. If you'd provided data and expected output, we could've offered you alternative pandas solutions.

Comment: Computing the nonzero mean of `.fillna(0).astype(int)` is a pretty roundabout way of getting the result of [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html).